# Error en la instalacion de mod_wsgi (Despliegue de una appweb con Apache2.4+Django)

Tags: python, django

**windows 10**
**Version de python :** 3.9.5
**Microsoft Visual C++ INSTALDADOS :**

- 2005 Redistributable
- 2008 Redistributable
- 2010 Redistributable
- 2012 Redistributable
- 2013 Redistributable
- 2015-2019 Redistributable

**El paso que provocó que el ERROR saltara fue:**
Escribir en la consola de windows CMD el comando : pip install mod_wsgi

**Error:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Downloading mod_wsgi-4.9.0.tar.gz (497 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 497 kB 595 kB/s
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mod-wsgi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
    Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pedropc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_dsrfksu\\mod-wsgi_877d22f796d64a268b6ca4fb022c29d5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pedropc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_dsrfksu\\mod-wsgi_877d22f796d64a268b6ca4fb022c29d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pedropc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fb6ztm8f\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files\python39\Include\mod-wsgi'
         cwd: C:\Users\pedropc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_dsrfksu\mod-wsgi_877d22f796d64a268b6ca4fb022c29d5\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pedropc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_dsrfksu\\mod-wsgi_877d22f796d64a268b6ca4fb022c29d5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pedropc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_dsrfksu\\mod-wsgi_877d22f796d64a268b6ca4fb022c29d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pedropc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fb6ztm8f\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files\python39\Include\mod-wsgi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Gracias de antemano, este error no me ha dejado desplegar el servidor

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Punto 4 principalmente, entre más detalles, mayor chance de obtener una buena respuesta :D

Comment: si , muchas gracias por la rapida atención, en cuanto se refiere al punto 4 del articulo q me sugiere leer, el paso q hizo q el ERROR saltara fue escribir en la consola de windows CMD el comando pip install mod_wsgi, y se genera todo el error antes mencionado,saludos

Comment: Eso que acabas de poner en la zona de comentarios, va en la pregunta, de ese modo es más sencillo que la gente vea qué estás haciendo, y se evita ir con una gran cantidad de comentarios. saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

El error menciona:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Instala y vuelve a intentar, existe la probabilidad que esto solucione tu caso.

Otra cosa que puedes intentar, es mediante NPM:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools